# What have I misunderstood in .net core partial view?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to make a page that shows two list of players, one for each team.

For that a partial view seemed like the correct approach, for starters I'm only trying with one partial view.

When I run it, I can see that the partialview .cs get a list from the database, but when it should be rendered in the partialview .cshtml it says the model is null.

I have a feeling that I'm missing something obvious, but what?

**Mainpage cshtml**

```
@using rd.Models
@model rd.Pages.p2.p2Model


@if (Model.HomeTeam != null)
{
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <partial name="_LineUp.cshtml" model="Model.HomeTeam"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

**mainpage cs**

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace rd.Pages.p2
{
    public class p2Model : PageModel
    {
        public _lineupModel HomeTeam { get; set; }


        private readonly rd.Models.rdnewContext _context;

        public p2Model(rd.Models.rdnewContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            HomeTeam = new _lineupModel(_context);
            HomeTeam.GetPlayers(1);
        }
    }
}
```

**partialview cshtml**

```
@page
@model rd.Pages.p2._lineupModel

//here it says that Player is null, even though it have just been populated
@if (Model.Player != null)
{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Player[0].PlayerName)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Player[0].PlayerNumber)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Player[0].PlayerActive)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Player[0].SortOrder)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Player[0].Team)
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.Player)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PlayerName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PlayerNumber)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PlayerActive)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SortOrder)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Team.TeamName)
                    </td>
                  
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

**partialview cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;


namespace rd.Pages.p2
{
    public class _lineupModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly rd.Models.rdnewContext _context;

        public _lineupModel(rd.Models.rdnewContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IList<Models.Player> Player { get; set; }

        //This one populate the Player list
        public void GetPlayers(int teamid)
        {
            Player =  (from pl in _context.Player where pl.TeamId == teamid select pl).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use debugging to check locals and see if the controller `Player` is null or if there is an error on you view.

Also partial views are supposed to be used similar to layouts except one step lower

Comment: I did use the debugger to establish that first in the .cs the Player is populated, and then right after that in the .cshtml that the same Player is null.   What do you mean by they are supposed to be used like layouts? Am I applying the concept of a partial view wrongly?

Comment: Can you try parsing it to a regular view and see if that works? I think your problem is that you are trying to parse more than one model into a view which is not possible

Comment: Do you mean like this? Instead of calling the main, I call the partialview directly?
Instead of this url: https://localhost:32774/p2/p2
I'll use this: https://localhost:32774/p2/_lineup



and with a minor change to the partialviews .cs where I comment out GetPlayers() and instead have this method

        public void OnGet()
        {
            Player =  (from pl in _context.Player where pl.TeamId == 1 select pl).ToList();
        }


Then it works as expected.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this: "I think your problem is that you are trying to parse more than one model into a view which is not possible"

Comment: you are using @ model rd.Pages.p2._lineupModel and @ model rd.Pages.p2.p2Model in one view. The rules are one model one view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I run it, I can see that the partialview .cs get a list from the database, but when it should be rendered in the partialview .cshtml it says the model is null.

> I have a feeling that I'm missing something obvious, but what?

As [this blog](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/partial-pages) mentioned, please note that ***the partial page should not feature an `@page` directive***. That would make the file a full Razor Page and will lead to a `NullReferenceException` related to the model not being declared when the framework attempts to invoke it.

To fix the issue, you can try to remove `@page` directive from your partial page `_LineUp.cshtml` , and query database and get list of `Player` from `p2` page model class directly.

*In p2.cshtml*

```
@page
@using rd.Models
@model rd.Pages.p2.p2Model
@{
}
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <partial name="_LineUp.cshtml" model="Model.Player" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

*In p2.cshtml.cs*

```
public class p2Model : PageModel
{
    public IList<Player> Player { get; set; }

    private readonly rd.Models.rdnewContext _context;

    public p2Model(rd.Models.rdnewContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        Player = GetPlayers(1);
    }

    public List<Player> GetPlayers(int teamid)
    {
        var player_list= (from pl in _context.Player where pl.TeamId == teamid select pl).ToList();

        return player_list;
    }
}
```

*In _LineUp.cshtml*

```
@model List<rd.Models.Player>

@if (Model!= null)
{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].PlayerName)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].PlayerNumber)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].PlayerActive)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].SortOrder)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].Team)
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PlayerName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PlayerNumber)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PlayerActive)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SortOrder)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Team.TeamName)
                    </td>

                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that worked!

I had been adding the partial view, by add -> new scaffolded item, and the putting a checkmark in create as partial view.

But apparently that does NOT create a valid partial view, since it have a @page directive at top.

Thank you so much for a very well described solution!